# Groovy update causing a ton of dead GroovyClassLoaders in PermGen

Tags: java, groovy, permgen

I have a Java 7 project that runs scripts every n minutes by n processes. Here is an example of the code that runs the scripts.

```
ScheduledFuture scheduledFuture = scheduledService.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try (GroovyClassLoader cl = new GroovyClassLoader()) {
                    // Load up reusable script modules in the class loader
                    Class scriptClass = cl.parseClass(scriptSource);
                    Foo script = optimizationClass.newInstance();

                    // Tell Groovy that we don't need class meta info
                    GroovySystem.getMetaClassRegistry().removeMetaClass(scriptClass);
                    script.run();
                    cl.clearCache();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    LOGGER.error("Failed to cleanup Groovy class loader, this will cause a memory leak", e);
                }
            }
        }, 0, scheduledRun, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        scheduledFuture.get();
```

For some reason with Groovy 2.1.7 there is no memory leak in Perm Gen. When upgrading to Groovy 2.3.8 or Groovy 2.2.0, Perm Gen keeps getting filled with dead Groovy class loaders.

> 0x000000071ada2cd0    33  488160  0x000000071b2493c8  dead    groovy/lang/GroovyClassLoader$InnerLoader@0x00000007c7b70ef8
>   0x00000007265883b8    33  488160  0x0000000725837270  dead    groovy/lang/GroovyClassLoader$InnerLoader@0x00000007c7b70ef8
>   0x00000007157b5da0    26  370736  0x000000072326f468  live    org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/callsite/CallSiteClassLoader@0x00000007c831d388
>   0x000000071ada1fb0    32  423944  0x000000071af03a98  dead    groovy/lang/GroovyClassLoader$InnerLoader@0x00000007c7b70ef8
>   0x0000000719d605b0    32  456520  0x000000071af04798  dead    groovy/lang/GroovyClassLoader$InnerLoader@0x00000007c7b70ef8
>   0x0000000725b82500    0   0   0x000000072326f468  dead    groovy/lang/GroovyClassLoader@0x00000007c74c33e8
>   0x00000007263eef80    34  532448  0x0000000726d5c678  dead    groovy/lang/GroovyClassLoader$InnerLoader@0x00000007c7b70ef8
>   0x000000072687b3c8    33  485288  0x0000000726c36340  dead    groovy/lang/GroovyClassLoader$InnerLoader@0x00000007c7b70ef8
>   0x0000000725d56db0    33  485288  0x000000072607bcc0  dead    groovy/lang/GroovyClassLoader$InnerLoader@0x00000007c7b70ef8

I wait until a Full GC happens but it seems that any version after Groovy 2.2 has been causing Perm Gen to fill up. I checked the release notes between the version I was at up to the updated version and I didn't notice any changes that would trigger this.

I checked on here for similar issues and tried a few suggestions but no luck. Any ideas as to the cause?

Update:
I did a Diff on GrepCode on GroovyClassLoader from 2.1.7 to 2.2.0 and there was no changes. I also took a heap dump file when the application was running and there wasn't any paths to GC roots for strong references.

The issue seems to be around here:

```
Class scriptClass = cl.parseClass(scriptSource);
Foo script = scriptClass.newInstance();
```

When I don't compile the script I got 0 Groovy ClassLoaders in Perm Gen. When I compile the script but don't run it, I get dead Groovy ClassLoaders.

Update:
Found the code that is causing the leak.

```
Foo script = scriptClass.newInstance();
```

Not sure how to fix this as I need to create a new instance in order to run the script.

Comment: Doesn't Java 8 eliminate PermGen woes? :) (in fact I'm also interested in why this would happen!)

Comment: Java 8 replaced PermGen space with Metaspace, which by default auto expands. However Java 8 does nothing about the actual leaks - you can still get OutOfMemoryError: Metaspace.

In case you want to read up on the why and how, feel free to check out my blog series on the subject: http://java.jiderhamn.se/2011/12/11/classloader-leaks-i-how-to-find-classloader-leaks-with-eclipse-memory-analyser-mat/

Comment: Upgrading to Java 8 right now is not a viable solution at the moment. Also that won't fix the issue why upgrading Groovy is causing this leak.

Comment: If you are sure there are no strong references, did you try using different Java versions? You can also try running the program with -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -XX:+CMSPermGenSweepingEnabled to see if that has an effect

Comment: @blackdrag I forgot to mention that I already have -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC and -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled enabled. The only reason this happens is when I upgrade Groovy. I upgraded from 2.1.7 to 2.1.9 and still ran into the issue. If I don't upgrade then the dead GroovyClassLoaders get cleaned up from Perm Gen. It's really frustrating. :(

Comment: I'd suggest that you track down the leak using the instructions on http://java.jiderhamn.se/2011/12/11/classloader-leaks-i-how-to-find-classloader-leaks-with-eclipse-memory-analyser-mat/ and then report your findings to both Groovy and me (as a comment in the blog). That way I might be able to make a workaround available through my ClassLoader Leak Prevention library (https://github.com/mjiderhamn/classloader-leak-prevention) until the Groovy team fixes the leak (assuming it is actually within Groovy).

Comment: @MattiasJiderhamn I updated to the latest Groovy version and am using the ClassLoader Leak Prevention library. I did a soak over the weekend and didn't run into any issues. I also ran a dummy project that creates Groovy ClassLoaders and they were getting cleaned up. At this point, I'm not sure what triggered the leak that I was experiencing.

Answer (score 5):

i had same problem when using groovy script for compiling and running.
I finally work out with these way:
1. if you work with java version under 7 , you can use codes below to clean your class after compiled

```
 public static void clearAllClassInfo(Class<?> type) throws Exception {
    Field globalClassValue = ClassInfo.class.getDeclaredField("globalClassValue");
    globalClassValue.setAccessible(true);
    GroovyClassValue classValueBean = (GroovyClassValue) globalClassValue.get(null);
    classValueBean.remove(type);
}
```

2. otherwise you are lucky, because you just need add an properties in SystemProperties

```
-Dgroovy.use.classvalue=true
```

Comment: I've been looking for a fix for a leak I was having and all I could find was stuff about the static MetaClassRegistry. But it was not the problem. I just put those options and the leak went off. Looks like there are a lot of different memory leaks in Groovy when used as a runtime compiler. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

We've had similar issues with a file parser written in groovy, memory leaks like a seave - when you do a lot of String manipulation. We also tried the clearCache() on the classloader and also  .removeMetaClass() with no use.

We finally got around this problem by compiling the groovy module as a jar file and including it in the project.

Comment: Sadly I can't use this option as I need the Groovy code to be outside the application. We store our Groovy code in the database and the application runs it. This is done so engineers can redeploy code instantly.